# Linux bash awk print word with special letter

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a URL:

[www.google.com/word/word1/word_2/word3/word4](http://www.google.com/word/word1/word_2/word3/word4)

I would like to use awk to print only the words that contain the `_` special character. Sometimes the folder hierarchy may change:

[www.google.com/word/word1/word2/word3/word_4](http://www.google.com/word/word1/word2/word3/word_4)

I was using this, but sometimes the folders are above `$6`:

`folder=$(echo "$url" | awk -F/ '{print $6}')`

I need to print the folder name between the `/` characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this works ... there may be more efficient approaches:

```
echo 'www.google.com/word/word1/word2/word3/word_4' | awk -F'/' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/_/){print $i}}}'
word_4
```

We just iterate over all fields and check if the word contains an underscore; if yes, print the word. Starting at two, assuming that the domain name doesn't change.

Thought of a non-iterative approach:

```
$ echo 'www.google.com/word/word1/word_2/word3/word4' | awk '{print gensub(/^.*\/([^/]+_[^/]*).*/,"\\1","1")}'
word_2
```

If it doesn't need to be awk - here a somewhat more elegant solution:

```
$ echo 'www.google.com/word/word1/word_2/word3/word4' | grep -oE '[^/]+_[^/]*'
word_2
```

Comment: May be worth noting that `gensub()` and `-o` are non-standard GNU extensions.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be just:

```
% echo 'www.google.com/word/word1/word_2/word3/word4' | tr -s '/' '\n'  |grep _
word_2
```

That is, change slashes to newlines, then print the resulting lines that contain an underscore.

If something other than the slash should also be considered a word separator, include them in the first quoted string. Or do it the other way around and list anything that can be part of a word:

```
% echo 'www.google.com/word/word1/word_2/word3/word4' | tr -sc 'a-zA-Z_0-9' '\n'  |grep _
word_2
```

Comment: Or if it's in a variable as per the Q, in some shells including bash as tagged: `echo "${url/\//$'\n'}" | grep _` . But since the Q asks to not check the first token -- which as a hostname _shouldn't_ contain _ but some do -- `| tail +2 | grep _` or `| sed '1d;/_/!d'`. Or with one (portable) awk `echo "$url" | awk -v RS=/ 'NR>1&&/_/'`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, well, idk, it says "print only the words that contain the `_`", without further specifying that some of them should be ignored (but then it doesn't exactly define "word" either)

Comment: The example in the Q has a hostname that is not a word by the usual definition (\w+) and does not say 'word', followed by multiple tokens that are words and do say 'word'. I thought that was clear enough.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I don't know if they agree on that usual definition of a word. Something like `six-pack` could also be reasonably considered a word.

Answer (score 2):

If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could extract the `/`-separated words that contain `_` with:

```
words=( ${(M)${(s[/])url}:#*_*} )
```

That would work regardless of what byte values those words might contain and doesn't involve forking a process or running an external utility.

`${(s[/])url}` `s`plits the variable on `/`. `${(M)array:#pattern}` expands to the elements of the array that `M`atch the pattern.

I can also be done in `bash`, but it's more cumbersome:

```
words=()
IFS=/; set -o noglob
for word in $url; do
  if [[ $word = *_* ]]; then
    words+=( "$word" )
  done
done
```

`awk` / `perl` would be more appropriate if you have a long list of URLs, one per line coming from some text stream / file.

With `perl`:

```
that-stream | perl -F/ -lae 'print for grep /_/, @F'
```